# Why does my Oracle client installation not appear in Windows Control Panel?

Tags: oracle, windows-7, control-panel

I have an Oracle client installed on my workstation.  tnsping reports:

> C:\temp> tnsping
>
> TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
>   on 06-JUL-2018 09:22:33
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

However, it does *not* appear in Control Panel Programs.  The only Oracle thing there (other than Java) is

> Oracle data Provider for .NET Help

I just want to understand this (apparent) disconnect.  Bingoogle found nothing (or I didn't ask the question the right way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, if you installed the client using "setup.exe", then - if it (or any other program you install) creates a registry key whose name is longer than 60 characters, it won't be displayed in "Programs" in Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an [Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html), there is no installer, there is no official windows application installation.

Instead, it's a Zip archive that you extract to a local folder and simply add it's 'bin' folder to your machine's PATH.

Or as the docs say..

> Installation
>
> See the Instant Client Home Page for more information about Instant
>   Client packages.
>
> 1. Download the appropriate Instant Client packages for your platform. All installations require the Basic or Basic Light package.
> 2. Unzip the packages into a single directory such as C:\oracle\instantclient_12_2
> 3. Add this directory to the PATH environment variable. If you have multiple versions of Oracle libraries installed, make sure the new
>      directory occurs first in the path

Comment: `tnsping` is not part of the Instant Client, thus your advise would not be valid.

Comment: that depends on WHAT version of the client - which they failed to say...and some folks try to copy over tnsping